# ¿ Como obtener el padre superior con JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cómo puedo yo capturar el padre superior de contenedores por ejemplo tengo esta estructura

```
<fieldset><!--padre de todos-->
 <div class="on">
<!--some conten-->

</div>

<div class="footer">
<!--con este boton necesito capturar el fieldset-->
 <button>Capturar padre superior</button>
</div>

</fieldset>
```

Necesito que al hacer `click` en el botón que esta dentro de el `footer` capturar el padre de todos, es decir el `fieldset`

**ejemplo**

```
$("button").click(function(){

    //en esta variable capturaria el padre del botón que es el  div con la clase footer
   var padreSuperior=$(this).parent()
})
```

¿Cómo puedo acceder al padre superior de todos mediante un click al botón?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podría usar [closest('parametro')](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) para obtener el primer elemento que coincida con el parámetro especificado, podría ser un ID, una clase o directamente un tag como en este caso. `fieldset`

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    //en esta variable capturaria el padre del boton que es el  div con la clase footer
   var padreSuperior=$(this).closest('fieldset');
   console.log(padreSuperior);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset><!--padre de todos-->
  <div class="on">
 <!--some conten-->

 </div>

 <div class="footer">
 <!--con este boton necesito capturar el fieldset-->
  <button>Capturar padre superior</button>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias! me fue util amigo!

Answer (score 4):

Para tu caso de uso te serviría hacer:

```
var padreSuperior=$(this).parent().parent();
```

Pero si no tienes certeza de cuán profundo pueda estar el botón dentro del DOM, puedes usar `closest`

```
var padreSuperior=$(this).closest('fieldsed');
```

`closest` puede ser tan específico como tú quieras, si además le das al fieldset una propiedad de clase.